# Are there any unix shells that support mouse reporting?

Tags: bash, shell, mouse, cursor

I am currently using bash on OSX (via iTerm2). Sometimes I have to run programs with a very lengthy set of command line arguments. If I find that I've mistyped, it takes way too long to arrow back to the mistake and fix it. I know some programs, such as nano, support mouse reporting for cursor positioning. Is this supported by any shells, or (even better) as an option to bash?

Comment: I know that there are zsh scripts that add mouse support, but haven't tried any.

Comment: In the standard MacOS Terminal, holding down `alt`/`option` while clicking the mouse will move your cursor to that location in the line. I haven't figured out how to enable select-and-cut or typing to replace selection, but this may help for your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you would benefit from investing a short amount of time in learning
some default `readline` keyboard shortcuts.  Note that [user606723's
answer](https://superuser.com/questions/322367/are-there-any-unix-shells-that-support-mouse-reporting/322386#322386)
above gives some basic ones but the <kbd>Home</kbd> and
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys do not work on all terminals.  Here are a
few of the ones I find the following most useful and which also work in more
terminals.

*(Unless otherwise noted, "word" means an alphanumeric string.)*

- <kbd>Alt-f</kbd>: go one *word* forward.
- <kbd>Alt-b</kbd>: go one *word* back.
- <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>: go to beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd>: go to end of line
- <kbd>Alt-d</kbd>: delete to end of *word*
- <kbd>Alt-Backspace</kbd>: delete to beginning of *word*
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd>: delete backwards to whitespace
- <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd>: paste most recently deleted text
- <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-f</kbd>: move backward/forward one character,
  equivalent to <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>: equivalent to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and
  <kbd>Delete</kbd>, respectively.

I list the last few because I find them more convenient than reaching for the
arrow keys or delete/backspace.  You can see how with these basic shortcuts
you can do quite a bit of editing rather easily.  But there are more:

- <kbd>Alt-.</kbd>: rotate through the last word (white-space delimited) of
  the previous lines in history.  Using it one gets you the last argument of the
  most recent command you typed.
- <kbd>Ctrl-_</kbd>: undo (incremental)
- <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>: search forward for character (like `f` in vim, but less
  convenient)
- <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>: reverse history search
- <kbd>Alt-0</kbd>...<kbd>Alt-9</kbd>: numeric argument to next command.  For
  example if you wanted to delete 4 words: <kbd>Alt-4</kbd><kbd>Alt-d</kbd>.  Or
  if you need 1024 `A`'s on the command line for some reason:
  <kbd>Alt-1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd>: delete from cursor position to beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>: delete from cursor position to end of line

And these are just a few of the ones I use - there are many more in the manpage.

Comment: I selected this answer because it's the one I think I will use, but these are all great solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know but ...

---

### History Expansion

to repeat the last command after correcting `teh` to `the`

```
^teh^the^
```

to repeat the last command that contained the word `foo` after changing the first occurrence of `bar` to `qax`

```
!?foo?:s/bar/qax/
```

---

### Line editing

you can use emacs-style editing commands to move quickly through the line.

I prefer vi mode `set -o vi` which means I can use <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> to move back and forwards a word at a time and use <kbd>f</kbd>`x` to move the cursor to the next occurrence of a specific character `x`.

Answer (score 1):

[GPM (General Purpose Mouse)](https://launchpad.net/gpm) is a mouse server for the console and xterm

EDIT: Apparently there's also a [version 2](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm2/).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an 'answer', but it is a solution. I am submitting it as an answer because I require the extra room.

Have you tried using a combination of <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

- <kbd>Home</kbd> - Will take to the **front** of the command.
- <kbd>End</kbd> - Will take to the **end** of the command.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> - Will take you a **"word"** to the **left.**
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> - Will take you a **"word"** to the **right.**

With these key combos, it should be alot easier to traverse back to your mistake =)